# Is this risky code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

```
class TicketChargesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.last

  # Amount in cents
  @amount = @ticket.amount

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => @ticket.event.title,
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
  end
end
```

Note that

```
@ticket=Ticket.find(params[:id])
```

does not work, I suppose because there isn't a model for ticket_charges and @ticket is in the tickets_controller? So my code works, but I am not sure if it's the proper way to wire this up, and dealing with money is scary! Thanks

Comment: Can't you charge it during the ticket creation? If you create two tickets before charging, you'll miss the first one.

Comment: OK, the sequence is the user enters his name and quantity of tickets he wants, the ticket order is saved and that triggers the Stripe modal. the Stripe form lives in the tickets/show view.

Comment: If the stripe form lives in tickets/show you do have the ticked's id, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand why @ticket=Ticket.find(params[:id] does not work. This is the error: Couldn't find Ticket with 'id'=

Comment: what's the url for tickets/show? Is it something like this? `/tickets/10`.

Comment: @ticket=Ticket.find(params[:id] does not work. This is the error: Couldn't find Ticket with 'id'=  The form in tickets/new is <%= form tag ticket_charges_path do %> and I don't know how to transfer the current ticket_id, handled by tickets_controller to the ticket_charges_controller. Ticket.last works.

Comment: Yes, events/1/tickets/10 is the url

Comment: Ok.. So you have the ticket's id on that form through `params[:id]`. You can create a hidden field to hold the ticket's id or even pass it through the url `ticket_charges_path(ticket_id: params[:id])`. In the controller params[:ticket_id] will be available.

Answer (score 0):

To get

```
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
```

to work, I had to use a hidden field in the form, passing in the object from tickets_controller to ticket_charges_controller and change the code to:

```
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
```

Thanks to Alexandre Angelim